# In_array php and string

Tags: php

I have the following php array session:

```
$_SESSION["test"] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
array_walk_recursive($_SESSION["test"],"prepareArray");

function prepareArray(&$item,$key){
    $item = "'" . $item . "'";
}
```

debugging `$_SESSION["test"`] outputs the following:

```
var_dump: 
array(7) { [0]=> string(3) "'1'" [1]=> string(3) "'2'" [2]=> string(3) "'3'" [3]=> string(3) "'4'" [4]=> string(3) "'5'" [5]=> string(3) "'6'" [6]=> string(3) "'7'" } 

print_r: 
Array ( [0] => '1' [1] => '2' [2] => '3' [3] => '4' [4] => '5' [5] => '6' [6] => '7' ) 

echo: 
Array

echo in_array('3',$_SESSION["test"],true);  //strict set to true (echoes nothing)
echo in_array('3',$_SESSION["test"],false); //strict set to false (echoes nothing)
```

I can't figure why this happens exactly. Any idea on this one?

Comment: -1: Broken testcase, doesn't show the issue. [Your code is fine](http://ideone.com/W5sORP) and produces `true` for both.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok, it is now updated, sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prepareArray` function is altering your values, you should be searching for "'3'" instead of '3', try this:

```
echo in_array("'3'",$_SESSION["test"],true);
echo in_array("'3'",$_SESSION["test"],false);
```

Comment: @0LLiena: Your code makes it so that your array elements are like `'1'`, `'2'` etc, but apparently you've been expecting to be able to find array elements `1`, `2` etc instead. It seems to be that you've become confused as to the difference between `'` as a character in a string, and `'` as a _delimiter_ for a string literal.